# json String transform to Java Bean

Tags: java, json-lib

When I run the code, it reports:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to ColorData at.....

The Code is:

```
public class JsonTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<ColorData> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ColorData data1 = new ColorData(1129, 0.35);
    ColorData data2 = new ColorData(1120, 0.39);

    list.add(data1);
    list.add(data2);

    Collections.sort(list);

    // Java list to json
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(list);

    // json to Java
    JSONArray jsonObject = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonArray);
    ArrayList<ColorData> resList = new ArrayList<ColorData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.size(); i++) {
        ColorData data = (ColorData) jsonObject.get(i);
        resList.add(data);
    }

}
}
```

After the Java List to Json, it's toString is:

```
[{"HSV":1120,"denominator":1,"numerator":1,"quantity":0.39},{"HSV":1129,"denominator":1,"numerator":1,"quantity":0.35}]
```

Then read this string back to `jsonObject`, and parse it into `ColorData`, store it into the resList.

Through `jsonObject.get(i)` I can get the each data such as `{"HSV":1120,"denominator":1,"numerator":1,"quantity":0.39}` , But how can I transform it to a ColorData instance ???

The `ColorData` Class are as follow:

```
public class ColorData implements Comparable<ColorData>{

private int HSV;
private double quantity;

private int numerator = 1;
private int denominator = 1;


// init the value
public ColorData (int HSV, double quantity) {
    this.HSV = HSV;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}


// getter and setter
public int getHSV() {
    return HSV;
}
public void setHSV(int hSV) {
    HSV = hSV;
}
public double getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public int getNumerator() {
    return numerator;
}
public void setNumerator(int numerator) {
    this.numerator = numerator;
}
public int getDenominator() {
    return denominator;
}
public void setDenominator(int denominator) {
    this.denominator = denominator;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ColorData o) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (this.quantity - o.quantity > 0)
    return -1;
   else if (this.quantity - o.quantity < 0)
    return 1;
   else
    return 0;
}


}
```

Comment: you can't cast `JsonObject` to `ColorData`, you need to instantiate new `ColorData` and set the values from jsonObject one by one, or use `GSON` lib

Comment: How can I set the values from jsonObject, because I can't get the value of field.

Comment: it depends on which JSON lib you are using, it could be `jsonObject.get(i).getString("JSON_FIELD_NAME")`, ex `jsonObject.get(i).getString("denominator")` you can use other getxxx() ex, getInt, getBool... etc

Comment: i have posted an answer with more details

Comment: I use json-lib-2.2.3-jdk13.jar.  But jsonObject.get(i).getString("JSON_FIELD_NAME") it can't works.  Should it cast to ` ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get(i)).getString(0)` ? But the parameter of getString is type Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read attributes one by one and set them in the data object.

```
ColorData data;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.size(); i++) {
        data = new ColorData();

        //{"HSV":1120,"denominator":1,"numerator":1,"quantity":0.39}
        data.setHSV(((JSONObject)jsonObject.get(i)).getInt("HSV"));
        data.setDenominator(((JSONObject)jsonObject.get(i)).getInt("denominator"));
        data.setNumerator(((JSONObject)jsonObject.get(i)).getInt("numerator"));
        data.setQuantity(((JSONObject)jsonObject.get(i)).getDouble("quantity"));

        resList.add(data);
    }
```

or you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) lib.

Comment: The Compiler reports :The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: it's not called for JsonArray, look at my answer again `jsonObject.get(i)`

Comment: you have miss-named the object, here `JSONArray jsonObject = ...` i think it would be better to name it `JSONArray mJsonArray = ...`

Comment: I hava try `jsonObjec.get(i).get(i).getInt("HSV")`, the compiler says The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: `data.setHSV(jsonObject.get(i).getInt("HSV"));
        data.setDenominator(jsonObject.get(i).getInt("denominator"));
        data.setNumerator(jsonObject.get(i).getInt("numerator"));
        data.setQuantity(jsonObject.get(i).getDouble("quantity"));`

Comment: oh sorry, the `get(i).get(i)` that's my mistyping, I really copy your answer, but the parameter of getXXX method is not type String, is Int.

Comment: `((JSONObject) jsonObject.get(i)).getInt("HSV")` it will be the correct answer, it should cast to JSONObject first.

Comment: if this worked then it's correct :) i told you its based on the library you are using.